# How can I keep UIImage in new position after Animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage

I am moving UIImages across the screen, they are cards. When they move across the screen, the images are generic card backs. When they land in the correct positions, they are supposed to stay in that position however they revert back to the original points. The original points of `playerCardOne`, `playerCardTwo`, and `playerCardThree` are `(60,28 , 90,28 , 120,28)` respectively.

Here is the code:

```
[playerCardOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"cardBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playerCardTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"cardBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playerCardThree setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"cardBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^(void){
                     playerCardOne.center = CGPointMake(120.0f, 28.0f);
                     playerCardTwo.center = CGPointMake(90.0f, 28.0f);
                     playerCardThree.center = CGPointMake(60.0f, 28.0f);
                         } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                     if (finished) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                         [playerCardOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playerCardOneTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                         [playerCardTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playerCardTwoTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                         [playerCardThree setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playerCardThreeTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     }
   }];
```

When the animation completes the front card images pop up and return to their original positions (i.e. `playerCardOne` should be at `(120.0, 28.0)` but reverts back to `(60.0, 28.0)`. How can I lock them in their new positions?

Comment: As soon as I set the image they pop up in their original positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AutoLayout you should animate the constraints instead of the frames of items.

There is some information on this at [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html) under Animation.

Basically you modify a constraint and then relayout over a time period.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    [myView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you turn-off `autolayout`, then the button should stay at the new position. The reason is because `autolayout` will use the current constraints to calculate the position when you update the views.

Comment: This solution worked however I would like to use auto layout for my project, is there a workaround?

Comment: @RyanCaskey My answer is the correct way to animate with AutoLayout.